# Is there are way to tell if standard input is empty without using getchar()?

Tags: c, input, user-input

In the FIRST code below "After" will not print until the user has entered a character and pressed enter because that standard input is empty. In the SECOND code the standard input is not empty and "Before" and "After" will both print immediately without waiting for the user. *Is there a way to tell if the standard input is empty so as to avoid the pause if the standard input is empty*?

**First Code**

```
int main() {
    
    printf("Before");
    char c = getchar();
    printf("After");
}
```

**Second Code**

```
int main() {
    ungetc( 'a', stdin );
    printf("Before");
    char c = getchar();
    printf("After");
}
```

Comment: Not in standard C. On Unix you can use the `FIONREAD` ioctl to test if there's anything available to read. But that just checks the underlying file descriptor, not the stdio buffer.

Comment: This is not possible in plain ISO C. However, most [platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_platform) provide extensions which may provide the functionality that you require. Therefore, if you want this to work on a particular platform, then you may want to specify to which platform (e.g. operating system and compiler) your question applies.

Comment: Define “empty”. Do you mean _available_ or _EOF_? If the latter, then just check whether `int getchar()` returns `EOF` (yes, `getchar()` returns `int`). If the former, then you will have to look at platform-specific solutions.

Comment: @Shadow43375 You can use Barmar's FIONREAD `ioctl()` or you could use `select()` to pause until there is data or check if there is no data available. Both methods are rather involved and neither play well with stdio.h (stdin/stdout).